# How can I add coordinate system / reference frame information to my data to avoid errors?

Tags: python, math, numpy, coordinates, physics

Often times when dealing with vectors, reference frames are implicitly enforced through documentation, comments, or worse, (human) memory. For example, I want to compute the torque acting on a body moving with a given velocity from a plane due to drag (using a simple drag model):

```
torque = velocity.dot(normal) * position.cross(normal)
```

Here, a plane that is `position` away from the center of the body has normal `normal`. The body is moving at velocity `velocity`. The torque calculated will only be correct if all three quantities are w.r.t the same reference frame or coordinate system. If the quantities are obtained from different frames, then they will have to be converted before computing the torque:

```
velocity_A = B_to_A * velocity_source    # velocity comes in frame B
position_A = C_to_A * position_source    # position comes in frame C
torque_A = velocity_A.dot(normal_source) + ...
```

This is tedious and error prone. I would like this information to explicitly tracked so that errors cannot occur:

```
A, B, C = Frame()
B.conversion_to(B_to_A)                  # etc. do this ONCE

velocity = Quantity(velocity_source, B)
position = Quantity(position_source, C)
normal = Quantity(normal_source, A)

torque = velocity.dot(normal) * position.cross(normal)
total_torque = torque + some_other_torque
# do other computations similarly

external_thing.send_data(total_torque.to(D)) # This expects torque in the D reference frame
```

Essentially, all of the conversions are gone and all the programmer needs to do is implement the math and proper computations. Internally, the framework will have freedom to choose how to compute most efficiently (using the least number of transforms). It can even avoid any computation unless values are needed outside of the framework to find optimizations, but the internals are not important.

How can one achieve such an interface? I am familiar with Python's pint (https://pint.readthedocs.org/en/0.6/) but it doesn't seem general enough to handle coordinate frames. C++ has Boost::units, but that also does not seem general enough. Ideally, the system would work with numpy arrays. I would like to avoid rewriting a vector library.

I have attempted to implement something like this in Python, but it looks like this:

```
vel = Quantity(velocity_source, B)
pos = Quantity(position_source, C)
normal = Quantity(normal_source, A)
computation = lambda vel, pos, normal: vel.dot(normal) * pos.cross(normal)
torque = compute(computation, vel=vel, pos=pos, normal=normal)
```

This is not ideal because everything needs to be done using functions or lambdas. Ideally, the system would get out of your way, e.g. you can add two `Quantity`s together without knowing they are `Quantity`s.

How can one best achieve such a framework? If the motivation isn't clear please let me know and I will clarify. This seems like something that would be very useful in any graphics or simulation engine, yet hours of searching have turned up nothing. Language doesn't particularly matter, I'm mostly looking for general ideas.

Comment: Are you prototyping or developing production code?  Classes (and subclassing arrays) are good if you know where you are going.  Functions are better, in my experience, when exploring ideas.  Use ordinary Python structures like arrays and dictionaries to group data arrays and values that need to be used together.

Comment: Mostly prototyping but would like to keep all the benefits of numpy or an existing library if possible. I could probably overload all the commonly used methods and do conversions before delegating to numpy, but that doesn't sound ideal.

Comment: Look at the code for masked arrays or matrix subclasses to see how much work is required to make a good ndarray subclass.  People do it, but my impression is that it can be a lot of work to do well.

Comment: A masked array is a ndarray subclass that contains 2 arrays, the data and the mask.  scipy.sparse has classes that behave like arrays, and contain arrays (or dictionary or list), but does not try to subclass ndarray.  recarray is another subclass, that adds a special .__getattr__ method.

Comment: Indeed, integrating with numpy seems like a lot of work. You're probably better off just doing your conversions first and then delegating to numpy, as you said. At least that's what you can start with. As for your issue with using lambdas, both C++ and python have operator overloading, so you can make `Quantity * Quantity` produce another `Quantity`. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you are looking to implement what Sympy provides in the vector module. Have a [look](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.2/modules/physics/mechanics/vectors.html) at the `ReferenceFrame` class.

```
from sympy.physics.vector import ReferenceFrame, express
from mpmath import radians

A = ReferenceFrame('A')
B = ReferenceFrame('B')

# define some relationship between the two systems like a rotation*
B.orient(A, 'Axis', [radians(90), A.z])

# define a vector in frame A
vector = [1, 0, 0]
vector_inA = vector[0]*A.x + vector[1]*A.y + vector[2]*A.z

print vector_inA
# >A.x

# determine the vector coordinates in frame B
vector_inB = express(vector_inA, B)

print vector_inA
# >6.12323399573677e-17*B.x - B.y
```

*Rotation is defined as anticlockwise around the z axis as the viewer looks in the direction of z for a right-handed Cartesian system